# Find blocking function in python/django app

Tags: python, django, blocking

When serving a request my gunicorn worker times out.

This is a big app and I'm not sure where it happens.

Is there an easy way to log all function calls so I can see the last call in which it blocked?

Comment: I had some problems like that in the past. In my case I changed the worker class to use `gevent` in order to handle many requests in the same time and my issue was solved.

Comment: @DaniloAkamine Thanks but in my case each single request is timing out, so I really have to find the function call that is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found a gunicorn hook called `worker_exit` which can be added to the config file. This hook is called when the worker exits as it does when timing out. In the hook a call to `traceback.print_exc()` is made which prints the stacktrace.

```
# gunicorn.py 

import traceback

def worker_exit(server, worker):
    traceback.print_exc();
```